# Excel: Relative vs. absolute path hyperlinks

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have an Excel spreadsheet located in a folder on a network drive.  I want to include hyperlinks to images.  These are in a sub-folder.  If I insert the hyperlinks in the spreadsheet cell, these are added with relative path.  Because of this if I email the sheet the hyperlinks are broken for the reader.

On the other hand if I copy the file somewhere else and insert hyperlinks as they were before in that original sub-folder, these hyperlinks are added with absolute path.  They work in the email.

How can I tell Excel to always put the absolute path for hyperlinks?

Comment: Better you share the image through Cloud.

Comment: The hyperlink function might solve your problem

Comment: Refer to this link: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/328440/description-of-link-management-and-storage-in-excel